# Proving that $\mu_{E}$ is a measure on (X,M)

Tags: measure-theory

Let (X, M, $\mu$) be a measure space and let E $\in$ M. For any A $\in$ M define $\mu_{E}$(A) = $\mu$(A $\cap$ E). Prove that $\mu_{E}$ is a measure on (X, M).

I'm a little lost as to how to attack this problem. I believe I should prove $\mu_{E}$ by intersecting all the sets with E prior to measuring anything. It's getting started on this that is becoming the difficult part.

Comment: You just need to verify the three defining properties of a measure, it's pretty trivial.

Comment: Just take intersection of the set with E. For countable additivity take E intersected with each set in the union. Same for the other properties.

Comment: I think you can just check wether $\mu_E:M\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ satisfies the definition of a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nonnegativity,
$$
\mu_E(A) = \mu(A \cap E) \ge 0. \quad \text{(Why?)}
$$
Next, check that $\mu_E(\varnothing) = 0$; this is also just a matter of plugging in the definition of $\mu_E$.

The final step is countable additivity. Let $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ be disjoint sets; we need to prove that
$$
\mu_E\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = \mu\left(A \cap \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) \tag{1}
$$
is equal to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_E(A) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A \cap A_i). \tag{2}
$$
Can you see how to transform (1) into (2)?

Comment: Thanks! the part that was confusing me the most was changing (1) into (2) but I believe I can figure the rest out from here.